# I can not install "git-lfs" on aws sagemaker notebook instance

Tags: git, amazon-sagemaker, apt

I Can not run `apt to install git-lfs` on sagemaker notebook instance. I want to run git commands in my notebook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the following commands to install git-lfs

```
!curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash

!sudo yum install git-lfs -y

!git lfs install
```

that should make it work

Answer (score 7):

Bit late to the conversation, but this might be useful to someone else.  To install `git lfs` in notebook:

```
!conda install -c conda-forge git-lfs
```

```
git lfs install
```

This approach doesn't require `sudo` which is a big plus!

Answer (score 5):

For using Hugging Face repo big files with git lfs, both in SageMaker notebooks and SageMaker Studio the above work only if you install the epel extras:

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y`

`curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash`

`sudo yum install git-lfs -y`
`git lfs install`

Note: in Studio you might need to run the 1st cmd after "sudo su"

Comment: Yup, Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The default OS for Sagemaker notebooks is Debian, use `apt-get` to install packages.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
apt-get install git-lfs
git lfs install
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Found the following [here](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-git-lfs-in-amazon-linux-2-aws-ec2/) and seems to work.

```
!sudo yum update -y
!sudo yum install amazon-linux-extras
!sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
!sudo yum update -y
!sudo yum install git-lfs -y
```

Answer (score 0):

this way works!
download rpm file from the url below:
https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/packages/el/7/git-lfs-3.4.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm/download

then run

```
sudo rpm -i git-lfs-3.4.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

then run

```
git lfs install
```